# Spring Boot Gradle dependencies in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project and I am trying to add Spring Boot to my Gradle dependencies. When a project is generated from the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) it creates the `developmentOnly` dependency configuration as seen below. It also creates the `testImplementation` dependency configuration.

The first `build.gradle.kts` below is my attempt at transferring these to a multiplatform project, which so far hasn't worked. I have marked the lines that have problems with comments, they are towards the bottom of the file. Afterward, I have put a normal Spring Boot `build.gradle.kts` for comparison.

How can these be put into a multiplatform project? Or, if they can't be added for some reason, set up the configuration in such a way that the same result is achieved.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.4.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13

repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/") }
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap") }
    maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx") }
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers") }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js {
        browser()
    }
}

kotlin.sourceSets["jsMain"].dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-react:16.9.0-pre.91-kotlin-1.3.61")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-react-dom:16.9.0-pre.91-kotlin-1.3.61")
    implementation(npm("react", "16.12.0"))
    implementation(npm("react-dom", "16.12.0"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-styled:1.0.0-pre.91-kotlin-1.3.61")
    implementation(npm("styled-components", "5.0.1"))
    implementation(npm("inline-style-prefixer", "5.1.1"))


    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.3")
}

//The problems begin here
val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath { //can't resolve runtimeClasspath
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly) //can't resolve extendsFrom
    }
}

kotlin.sourceSets["jvmMain"].dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools") //error because of above where developmentOnly is defined
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") { //can't resolve testImplementation
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test") //can't resolve testImplementation

}
```

**Normal `build.gradle.kts` with Spring Boot (no issues)**

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.4.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    war
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}
```